# Issue with importing image to microk8s

Tags: microk8s

Rarely when importing a docker tar file to the microk8s using the command below It looks like the command finished successfully but the image was not imported, it happened twice on two different servers. when rerun the same command the image is imported correctly

```
microk8s ctr image import file.tar
```

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04 lts

The command is perform from the tar directory or with a full path to the tar file.

Search and didn't find any information about this issue.

Any idea what the problem or where to start the digging?